# Best approach to solve error calc with large integers wihout any library

Tags: javascript, integer, numbers

I participated on a proggramming contest last week. I used javascript to solve the problems, but I found an error working with big integers. First, this is the code:

```js
const solve03 = (n) => {
  n++;
  const times = Math.floor(n / 4);
  return n - 2 * times;
};
console.log(solve03(87123641123172368));
console.log(solve03(81239812739128371));
```

The output with js are:

```
43561820561586184
40619906369564184
```

I tested the same code with python (that supports large integers):

```py
def solve03(n):
    n += 1
    times = n // 4
    return n - 2 * times

print(solve03(87123641123172368))
print(solve03(81239812739128371))
```

And the outputs are:

```
43561820561586185
40619906369564186
```

I need a way to rewrite the code in js to solve the error calc problem, also, I known there are many libraries to support bigintegers operations, but the contest doesn't allow them.

Comment: You're hitting the integer limits of JS. Use [`bigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead for this

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet using BigInt! It will handle the large integers well

```js
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);

$("input").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  let aBigInt = BigInt(e.target.value);
  aBigInt++;
  const times = aBigInt / BigInt(4); //always returns floored
  const result = aBigInt - BigInt(2) * times;
  $("div").innerText = result;
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
<div></div>
```